# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cfnetwork

After my App stays in the background state for a long period of time (~60 seconds) and then returning to the active state the App crashes, and sometimes shows this error message, then immediately is in a locked state, like if there is a blocking function, that doesn't allow user interaction, then quickly crashes.

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2016-06-21 21:33:35.355 Slydde[317:26662] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

I have removed the ATS to ensure this isn't the issue:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Also, when using the app normally I never see this error, I only ever see this error when returning to the app from the background state.

The worst part is that when connected to the Xcode debbuger, Xcode shows no breakpoint exception pointing out what went wrong.

I also know that our server is TLSv1.2 SSL and is NOT self signed. Which other posts seem to point as an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out issue was with the third party appanalytics.io that I was using.

After I commented it out in the podfile removing it, the error was gone. As for what exactly it was doing when returning to an active state in my iOS app I am unsure. I will message the developer with the issue.

```
#pod 'AppAnalytics'
```